# How can I force a CSS animation of an element to start from the same location as the previous animation finished?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have an image that I want to move a certain distance (always the same) and a certain direction (specified in an array) on each mouse-click.  The first click moves it in the direction specified in the first array element, the second in the second and so on.

This works fine unless I ask it to move in the same direction twice in a row.  In that case it moves instantly to the finishing position with no animation, as if it had started the animation there, although the debugger shows the location, as defined by unitElement.style.left as corresponding correctly to its appearance on-screen.

The HTML, with four transformations and an image to move:

```
<style>
    .unit { width: 60px; height: 60px; position: absolute; }

    @keyframes N {100% {transform: translate(0px, -60px);}}
    @keyframes E {100% {transform: translate(60px, 0px);}}
    @keyframes S {100% {transform: translate(0px, 60px);}}
    @keyframes W {100% {transform: translate(-60px, 0px);}}
</style>

<body>
    <img src="test.png" class="unit" id="F1" />
</body>
```

The function that is called on the click event:

```
function nextPulseAnimate() {
    pulse++;
    for(var index = 0; index < units.length; index++) {
    
        var unit = units[index];
        var direction = unit.moves[pulse-1]
        
        var unitElement = document.getElementById(unit.name);

        //ensure that the image is starting from the right place
        unitElement.style.left = unit.start.x;
        unitElement.style.top = unit.start.y;

        unitElement.style.animation = direction + " 2s ease-in-out forwards";
    }

    //then re-set the locations ready for next pulse
    //If this is not done, each animation will start from the unit's original location
    for(var index = 0; index < units.length; index++) {
        var unit = units[index];
        var direction = unit.moves[pulse-1]
            
        switch (direction){
         case "N":
             unit.start.y -= 60; 
             break;
         case "E": 
             unit.start.x += 60;
             break;
         case "S":
             unit.start.y += 60;
             break; 
         case "W": 
             unit.start.x -= 60;
             break;
         }
    }
}
```

The "unit" referred to in the function is derived from a global array of objects that looks like this (in practice it will have  a couple of dozen elements):

```
units = [
    {name: "F1", start: {x: 0, y: 0}, moves: ["S", "E", "E", "E"]}
];
```

For completeness, there is one other global variabe defined (and used above):
pulse = 0

Comment: provide css `.unit` rule definition. How. your img is positioned static, relative, absolute, or fixed? A minimal reproducible code would be really nice.

Comment: Sure.  Here is the css definition for .unit:
.unit {
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
position: absolute;
}

Comment: I mean the entire css rule like `.unit{ position: absolute; height:20px}`. update your opening post/question

Comment: In second for loop you are setting units to fixed coordinates they are not actually their last locations. There is a DOM event `onAnimationEnd` you can use that to update last coordinates. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event

Comment: That was the entire .css definition for .unit I posted.  I have updated the OP at your request.  Thank you - I will look into onAnimationEnd, but is there a reason you think that will work better than iterating through the animated elements to re-set their starting co-ordinates?  Bear in mind that the code above works perfectly unless the same direction  is called for twice in a row.

Comment: I tried using the onAnimationEnd event, calling the following function to re-set the stye:
function setLocation() {
 this.style.left = this.offsetLeft
 this.style.top = this.offsetTop
}
As I expected, this sets to the original (pre-animation) location rather than the final one.  But perhaps you meant I should derive the final location in some other way??

This, in fact, is why I introduced the second for-loop in the first place.  It works fine, remember, except when the same direction appears twice in a row.

Comment: The twice in a row problem: when you set the same animation name the system won’t animate because it thinks it’s already done it. You need to clear it and reset in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I mean:

```js
units = [{name: "F1", start: { x: '0px', y: '0px'},
    moves: ["S", "E", "E", "N", "W", "W"]
  },
  { name: "F2", start: { x: '120px', y: '60px' },
    moves: ["N", "W", "W", "S", "E", "E"]
  }
];

var pulse = 0;

function init() {
  document.body.addEventListener("click", nextPulseAnimate);

  for (var index = 0; index < units.length; index++) {
    var unit = units[index];
    var unitElement = document.getElementById(unit.name);
    unitElement.style.left = unit.start.x;
    unitElement.style.top = unit.start.y;

    unitElement.addEventListener('animationend', (event) => {
      document.body.addEventListener("click", nextPulseAnimate);
      var e = event.target;
      /* get position relative to viewport */
      var r = e.getBoundingClientRect();
      e.style.left = r.left + 'px';
      e.style.top = r.top + 'px';
      /* remove animation so that you can use it again */
      e.style.animation = 'none';
    });
  }
}

function nextPulseAnimate() {
  pulse++;
  if (pulse < 7) {
    document.getElementById('stats').innerText = 'Moves: ' + pulse + '/6';
    //don't let user click while animation is going on
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', nextPulseAnimate);
  }

  for (var index = 0; index < units.length; index++) {
    var unit = units[index];
    var direction = unit.moves[pulse - 1]
    var unitElement = document.getElementById(unit.name);
    unitElement.style.animation = direction + " 2s ease-in-out forwards";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh
}

p {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40vh;
}

.unit { width: 60px; height: 60px; position: absolute; }

@keyframes N {100% {transform: translate(0px, -60px);}}
@keyframes E {100% {transform: translate(60px, 0px);}}
@keyframes S {100% {transform: translate(0px, 60px);}}
@keyframes W {100% {transform: translate(-60px, 0px);}}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="init()">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/60x60/000/fff.jpg" class="unit" id="F1" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/60x60/a0a/fff.jpg" class="unit" id="F2" />
  <p id=stats>Click anywhere to trigger moves</p>
</body>

</html>
```